# Excel validation rule Not working (hack)

Tags: excel, validation

Seems to `Microsoft Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.9126.2259) 32 bit` validation rule can be hacked by placing reference to other cell in validation cell.

for example put data validation into A1

[image]

Try to add value 10, and you get error msg

[image]

But now put value 10 to B1, in A1 put reference to B1 and restriction is broken.
Just select A1 cell and put =B1 enter, sometimes you need to provide in B1 right value, after you can change it

[image]

So how to disable such kind of hacks?

Comment: You can use VBA to enforce validation rules, but ultimately if a user's determined to break it then they'll find a way to do so.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? If I use the same steps, the validation works even when I use a reference to another cell. I have Excel 2010 (Windows)

Comment: It should fail as a reference is not a whole number. How are you adding this reference please?

Comment: I managed to reproduce the problem which doesn't make me very happy, I'm looking into it rn

Comment: You'll have to go for VBA, custom rules suffer from the same problem, worksheet protection doesn't have an option to prevent users from writing formulas, disabling "=" while users have a cell in A column selected might work.